# Angular 2 routerLink is not clickable

Tags: angular2-routing

I am trying to use routerlinl, but somehow it is not clickable. Please can someone help. Following are the codes:

```
**app.module.ts:**

import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
.....
@NgModule({....})
imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: 'employees', component: EmployeesComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'index', component: IndexComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/index' }

])
],


**app.component.html:**

<h1>App (root) component</h1>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li>
    <a routerlink="/login" routerLinkAction="active">Login</a>
</li>
</ul>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>


**app.component.ts:**
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
....
```

(The .... means there are codes but not putting here due to relevance).

Comment: Try to reproduce on stackblitz

Comment: Besides maybe you have some exceptions in the console huh?

Comment: nah...nothing in the console :(...its just that the link is not clickable...

Comment: Its not clickable because `href` is not generated. Reproduce on stackblitz so we can try to solve the proble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `routerlink` to `routerLink`

like

```
routerLink="/login"
```

not

```
routerlink="/login"
```

Care about letter casing as selectors are case sensitive.